# Windows utility to render which key I am pressing on-screen

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, on-screen-keyboard

I'm giving training to a large group of people remotely and will be covering a number of application shortcut keys.

I've seen [MousePose](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/)'s on-screen display of keystrokes; is there a way to get this same effect but for key presses?

[image: MousePose Screenshot]

I do not need anything fancy, just key presses displayed on screen where they can be captured by meeting software during a screen share.

I haven't been able to figure this out myself.

Comment: If this question is off-topic on Super User, can people at least write what of the stack-exchange sites is appropriate for this question?

Comment: @sdbbs Possibily https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[KeyPosé](https://github.com/AxDSan/KeyPose) is a **free** alternative to MousePosé for Windows. You can see it in action in the [screencast](http://katastrophos.net/magnus/blog/keypose/keypose.html).

Here is a sample screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @richard you're more than welcome!

Comment: I think it has some issues. You cannot change the position where you display the keys, sometimes the grey zone keeps showing even if you're not pressing a key, also the win/super key isn't displayed. Combinations which involves more than two keys pressed, like ctrl+alt+c, are displayed in a weird way, like first CTRL, then ALT (I suppose it should display CTRL+ALT) and finally CTRL+ALT+C. Is better than nothing, but I think there are better options.

Comment: Doesn't register Tab keys for some reason...

Comment: Doesn't register WIN combinatoins, did not show CTRL+SHIFT+ESC. Meh.

Comment: This program doesn't work for me.

Comment: Use Carnac below. I tested both and Carnac gives you various visual options. https://github.com/bfritscher/carnac/releases/tag/v3-beta

Comment: KeyPosé is not configurable in any way and only displays last character typed (would be nice to see some history). Also the linked screencast requires you download a player.

Comment: link provided is old and to a potentially unsafe ZIP, here is the source: https://github.com/AxDSan/KeyPose

Comment: It does not register Windows key.

Answer (score 34):

I highly recommend [**Carnac The Magnificent**](http://carnackeys.com/). It's nicely executed, nicely designed and [open sourced on GitHub](https://github.com/Code52/carnac) project that really solves this problem well.

> A keyboard logging and presentation utility for presentations, screencasts, and to help you become a better keyboard user.

[image: Screenshot]

There is a fork with visualization of mouse input here: https://github.com/bfritscher/carnac/releases

Comment: Interesting, but not as beautiful rendering as KeyPosé.

Comment: The project page provides only a `carnac.application` file, the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSUDfzUkwnc shows a `Carnac.exe`. Just later I realized that I can launch `carnac.application` in Windows and it downloads and installs the program. I found the zip/exe also here: https://github.com/downloads/Code52/carnac/Carnac.zip

Comment: @Basj Carnac is much more "beautiful" than KeyPosé (which only shows the letters as plain text). With Carnac you can change the appearance of the keys shown (font size, opacity, colors).

Comment: @KaiNoack I mean the default style of Carnac is not as stylish / minimalist as Keyposé. The default design should be improved ;)

Comment: How can I change the position of the keystroke display area? I can seem to find any documentation.

Comment: @jdhao Double-click the Carnac icon in the notification area, then you can customize the location on screen. You can then save/set defaults etc.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. well done thank you for the reference

Comment: This shows modifier keys *after* the entire shortcut is finished.

Comment: Just FYI: KeyPosé currently has 90 stars while Carnac has 2.9k, so it seems like the more popular option (not saying the better one)

Answer (score 11):

I would like to share my tool -- keycastow.

https://brookhong.github.io/2014/04/28/keycast-on-windows.html

[image]

Comment: Great thing! Also LICECap is great too, didn't know about one :)

Comment: @brookhong what did you use to create the animated giff?

Comment: @RicardoC It's licecap, http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: Microsoft Security Essentials classifies this as a threat. Oh well!

Comment: So does Avast. It is a false alarm, the software being open source, it can't possible hide a trojan. *However* running this makes the cursor jittery, and key input laggy.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox are both giving me warnings for https://brookhong.github.io/2014/04/28/keycast-on-windows.html http://imgur.com/a/jcdyB, and the page does not load if I ignore the warning

Comment: This tool is not downloadable as a binary; you have to build it yourself which for me is an issue because I don't have permission.

Comment: I just compiled and executed it and works well!! This is great!

Answer (score 7):

I've written an AutoHotkey_L script for this purpose.

To run it, use [AutoHotkey_L](https://ahkscript.org/) ([direct dl](https://ahkscript.org/download/ahk-install.exe)), it's FOSS. Also, with AutoHotkey you can compile script to EXE (simply `Ahk2Exe.exe /in` [`DisplayPressedKeyOnScreen.ahk`](https://github.com/LogicDaemon/PersonalUseScripts/blob/master/misc/DisplayPressedKeysOnScreen.ahk)`/out`[`DisplayPressedKeyOnScreen.exe`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlbqhyxjzb22y4q/DisplayPressedKeysOnScreen.exe?dl=0) ).

It can display pressed keys OSD-like or standard Tool-tip near mouse cursor.
Also, it displays mouse button clicks and wheel scrolling.

(note that frame & blurring is done for illustration purposes, the script itself only displays text w/o any disturbances)
[image: Screenshot]

Heres's the script (copy and paste to notepad, save as `DisplayPressedKeysOnScreen.ahk`):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
#InstallKeybdHook
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 500

;This work by LogicDaemon is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.

Global IdleDelay, LargeDisplay

IdleDelay:=3000

LargeDisplay:=1
; 0 = Tooltip near mouse pointer
; 1 = Big pane at screen bottom

;TrayTip %A_ScriptName%, Чтобы выйти`, нажмите правую клавишу Windows
TrayTip %A_ScriptName%, To Exit`, press the Right Windows logo key.

InputHook := InputHook("BCL1qMV*", "", "")
InputHook.KeyOpt("{All}", "INV")
InputHook.OnKeyDown := Func("OnKeyDown")
InputHook.OnKeyUp := Func("OnKeyUp")
InputHook.OnEnd := Func("RegisterKey")
Loop {
    InputHook.Start()
    InputHook.Wait()
}

return

RWin::
    ExitApp

~*LButton::
~*RButton::
~*MButton::
~*XButton1::
~*XButton2::
    MouseTooltip(SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 3), 1)
    return

~*LButton Up::
~*RButton Up::
~*MButton Up::
~*XButton1 Up::
~*XButton2 Up::
    MouseTooltip(SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 3, -3), 0)
    return

~*WheelDown::
~*WheelUp::
~*WheelLeft::
~*WheelRight::
    MouseTooltip(SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 3), 1)
    MouseTooltip(SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 3), 0)
    return

MouseTooltip(mbuttons, state){
    RegisterKey(mbuttons, state)
}

TooltipOff:
    If LargeDisplay
        Gui Hide
    Else
        Tooltip
    lastStatesText := {}
    return

OnKeyDown(inputHook, VK, SC) {
    RegisterKey(inputHook, 1, VK, SC)
}

OnKeyUp(inputHook, VK, SC) {
    RegisterKey(inputHook, 0, VK, SC)
}

RegisterKey(inputHook, kstate := 1, VK := 0, SC := 0) {
    local
    global IdleDelay, lastStatesText, inputString
    static keyStates := {}, prevKey, lastPressed, prevState, repeated := 0
         , KeyMappingToName := { (Chr(27)): "Escape"
                               , (Chr(32)): "Space"
                               , (Chr(10)): "Enter" }
         , SkipRepeat := { "LShift": ""
                         , "RShift": ""
                         , "LControl": ""
                         , "RControl": ""
                         , "LAlt": ""
                         , "RAlt": ""
                         , "LWin": ""
                         , "RWin": "" }
         , StringEndKeys := { "{Enter}": ""
                            , "{Escape}": ""
                            , "{Tab}": ""
                            , "{Up}": ""
                            , "{Down}": ""
                            , "{PgUp}": ""
                            , "{PgDn}": "" }
    
    If (VK || SC) {
        singleKey := GetKeyName(Format("vk{:02x}sc{:02x}", VK, SC))
    } Else If (!IsObject(inputHook)) {
        singleKey := inputHook
    }
    textKey := StrLen(singleKey) == 1 ? singleKey : "{" singleKey "}"
    keyStatesText := ""
    For key, state in keyStates
        If (state && key != singleKey)
            keyStatesText .= key "+"
    keyStates[singleKey] := kstate
    If (kstate && lastPressed == textKey && keyStatesText == lastStatesText) {
        If (!SkipRepeat.HasKey(singleKey))
            repeated++
    } Else {
        If (kstate) {
            If (repeated) {
                inputString .= (repeated > 4 || StrLen(lastPressed) > 1) ? "×" . repeated+1 : StrRepeat(lastPressed, repeated)
                , repeated := 0
            }
            If (keyStatesText != lastStatesText || StringEndKeys.HasKey(lastPressed))
                inputString := textKey, lastStatesText := keyStatesText
            Else If (StrLen(inputString) < 15)
                inputString .= textKey
            Else
                inputString := "…" SubStr(inputString, -15) textKey
            lastPressed := textKey
        }
    }
    ShowKeys((lstate ? keyStatesText : lastStatesText) . inputString . (repeated ? ("×" . repeated+1) : (kstate ? "↓" : "↑")))
    prevKey := singleKey, prevState := kstate
    
    SetTimer TooltipOff, % -IdleDelay
}

ShowKeys(text) {
    global GUIx, GUIy, GUIw, GUIh
         , blkOsdCtrlName, blkOsdCtrlName2
         , MonitorLeft, MonitorRight, MonitorBottom, MonitorTop
    
    If (LargeDisplay) {
        CoordMode Mouse, Screen
        MouseGetPos MouseX, MouseY

        InitLargeDisplay(MouseX, MouseY)
        
        If ((!GUIy) || (MouseX >= MonitorLeft && MouseX <= MonitorRight && MouseY >= GUIy && MouseY <= (GUIy+GUIh)) ) {
            If (MouseY < (MonitorTop + (MonitorBottom - MonitorTop) / 2) )
                GUIy := MonitorBottom - (MonitorBottom - MonitorTop) * 0.2
            Else
                GUIy := MonitorTop + (MonitorBottom - MonitorTop) * 0.2
        }
        
        GuiControl Text, blkOsdCtrlName, %text%
        GuiControl Text, blkOsdCtrlName2, %text%

        Gui, Show, x%GUIx% y%GUIy% NoActivate
    } Else {
        Tooltip % text
    }
}

InitLargeDisplay(MouseX, MouseY) {
    global GUIx, GUIy, GUIw, GUIh
         , blkOsdCtrlName, blkOsdCtrlName2
         , Monitor, MonitorLeft, MonitorRight, MonitorBottom, MonitorTop
    static guiInitialized := False
    ;Initializing GUI / reinitializing after changing monitor
    ;modded func originated from http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8190-osd-function/

    If ( (   MouseX < MonitorLeft
          || MouseX > MonitorRight
          || MouseY < MonitorTop
          || MouseY > MonitorBottom)
        || !guiInitialized) { ; mouse is outside of last screen GUI was positioned at
        ;80 SM_CMONITORS: Number of display monitors on the desktop (not including "non-display pseudo-monitors"). 
        SysGet monCount, 80
        Loop % monCount
        {
            SysGet Monitor, Monitor, %A_Index%
            If (MouseX >= MonitorLeft && MouseX <= MonitorRight && MouseY >= MonitorTop && MouseY <= MonitorBottom) {
                found := true
                break
            }
        }

        If (!found) ; mouse cursor not found on any screen, fallback to default monitor
            SysGet Monitor, Monitor
        
        GUIx := MonitorLeft
        , GUIw := MonitorRight - MonitorLeft
        , GUIh := (MonitorBottom - MonitorTop) * GUIw * 0.00003
        If (GUIh > ((MonitorBottom - MonitorTop) * 0.3))
            GUIh := (MonitorBottom - MonitorTop) * 0.3
        
        opacity:="230"
        , fname:="Tahoma"
        , fsize:=GUIh * 0.65 ; really, pixel = 0.75 point, but with 0.75 lowercase letter with lower part (like "g") will get cut
        , fcolor:="cccccc"
        , bcolor:="222222"
        , fformat:="600"
        
        If (guiInitialized)
            Gui Destroy
        Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
        Gui Margin, 0, 0 ;pixels of space to leave at the left/right and top/bottom sides of the window when auto-positioning.
        Gui Color, ffffff ;changes background color
        Gui Font, s%fsize% w%fformat%, %fname%

        ; 0x80 = SS_NOPREFIX -> Ampersand (&) is shown instead of underline one letter for Alt+letter navigation
        Gui Add, Text, c%bcolor% Center +0x80 w%GUIw% h%GUIh% BackgroundTrans VblkOsdCtrlName, tesT test test
        Gui Add, Text, c%fcolor% Center +0x80 w%GUIw% h%GUIh% BackgroundTrans VblkOsdCtrlName2 xp-3 yp-3 , tesT test test
        
        WinSet ExStyle, +0x20 ; WS_EX_TRANSPARENT -> mouse klickthrough
        WinSet TransColor, ffffff %opacity%

        guiInitialized := True
    }
}

StrRepeat(str, cnt) {
    If (cnt<1)
        return ""
    o := str
    Loop % cnt-1
        o .= str
    return o
}
```

Comment: I tried to start "DisplayPressedKeyOnScreen.exe" on Win7 64bit. I get the error message `Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.` Is the exe-file a standalone? Or do I have to install AutoHotkey beforehand?

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV I'm sure it's standalone. Also, I just downloaded and successfully launched it on Win 8.1 32-bit. Can we compare MD5? Mine is d788516439ed743b3553eb3ae7b9082c, and file size is 332 288 bytes.

Comment: The file that I downloaded from your [link above](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2t69kbj7serro7z/DisplayPressedKeysOnScreen.exe) shows me MD5: D788516439ED743B3553EB3AE7B9082C and file size 332 288. So it should be the exact same file. It is also weird that after the error message in Windows 7, the virus scanner Panda Cloud popped up, moving the 'malicious' file to quarantine.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV then apparently it's antivirus denied access to file when you tried to launch it, that's why you received Windows message that you can't access it. Though I dunno why it blocks, you can check: it's standard autohotkey binary joined with plaintext (but reformatted) script source.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV sorry, it's not plaintext. It's compreseed with [mpress](http://www.matcode.com/mpress.htm), which was included with AutoHotkey. Anyway, you can dowload standalone autohotkey binary ([exe.zip](http://ahkscript.org/download/ahk-u32.zip)) and drag-and-drop script on it to launch, just to see if that script will fit you. If so, you can either to keep it this way (just create a shortcut with «"path-to-ahk\autohotkey.exe" "path-to-script\script.ahk"» in "Object" field) or compile it yourself (takes 1 min to dl & install autohotkey and 5 sec to compile).

Comment: Dropbox removed it.

Comment: @Amina ty, I guess that's accidental move of dropbox folders by me. Will fix my post.

Comment: Can this AHK script be amended so that it track artifical keyboard entry, from say WinController Android App? I looked in the AHK docs but could not find anything.

Comment: @SteveWaring currently, to get pressed key, it uses [Input operator](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm), docs on which say: «by default, artificial input is also captured». Replace «Input SingleKey, L1 V M I B,» to «Input SingleKey, L1 V M B,», it should work.

Comment: @SteveWaring also, remove «, "P"» from each GetKeyState. For example: «GetKeyState("LControl", "P")» → «GetKeyState("RControl")»

Comment: Is there anyway to make this a function that shows text passed into the function so it can be used in my own scripts to show window of action my script performs on screen

Comment: @JasonDavis actually display is done by function, `ShowKeys()`. It needs init though, that's in auto-execute section of the script inside `If LargeDisplay {…}` block.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a small Windows app called [QiPress](http://aalapshah.in/qipress). It has controls to change the look-n-feel, display or ignore certain key-groups, even add static text (your own name or company name for example). Positioning is possible by disabling click-through and click-dragging the pop-up. There are other features which you probably may not require, but it covers mostly what you want.

Comment: currently 30 USD

Comment: To clarify on the versions:
Free Version: For personal, non-commercial use. Some advanced features disabled (like various language keyboards, multiple monitors, joystick display etc.). No time limitation.
Paid Version: For all uses. All advanced features enabled. No time limitation.

Comment: Why is it password protected? Virustotal says it is a virus.

Comment: This is because exes are not allowed in my hosting account file system. Also, the common exe was both x86 and x64/amd64 compatible, and I found that because of x86 compatibility, there was some signature in the exe which caused issues with anti-virus. 2 months ago I removed x86 compatibility, and VirusTotal seems to be okay with it, you can try again now. More details on virus false-positives are also on the website.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the on screen keyboard to show key presses that comes with windows. When you type on your physical keyboard the on screen one highlights said key.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, but the only modifier key that highlights is the Shift key.

Comment: In windows 7, type "keyboard" in the start menu search box, and select "On-Screen Keyboard"

Comment: It doesn't for me (win 10).

Answer (score 1):

[PointerFocus](http://www.pointerfocus.com) can display your keystrokes.

Comment: currently 12.50 USD

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot customize / ignore certain keys.

Answer (score 1):

[Presentation Pointer](http://www.presentation-assistant.com/ppointer/) is a best alternative to MousePosé for Windows. It provides Pointer Effect, Mouse Clicks Effect, Keystrokes and even allows you to draw freely on the screen but not lock the screen. That's really an advantage of the program.

Comment: ...currently 30 USD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PassMark KeyboardTest](http://www.passmark.com/products/keytest.htm) (Free 30 day evaluation, then US$24.00 to purchase.)

[image]

FYI:

- A similar question was asked on SO: [How to display pressed keyboard shortcuts on screen during presentations or screencasts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3529329/395857)
- A similar question was asked for OS X: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/62168/20338
- A related question was asked on software recommendations (the OP asks the program to display the keys the user is currently pressing while using other programs. It should show all the keys pressed, and as soon as the user releases a key - it should disappear.):  [Utility to display on screen the currently pressed keys](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18301/903)