# Can I have Windows show the state of modifier keys on the screen?

Tags: windows, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows utility to render which key I am pressing on-screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/104421/windows-utility-to-render-which-key-i-am-pressing-on-screen)

In OS X, when you press some modifier keys like Command or Option, there's feedback on the screen, to indicate that you're currently pressing this key. Is there a similar utility on Windows?

Comment: If you mean modifiers such as Cmd, Option (Alt) and Control, these are provided by specialized presentation tools like [Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/), and used e.g. in screencasts, so you can see what keys are pressed. Or do you mean the information bezels when changing volume or screen brightness?

Comment: I mean modifier keys like cmd and alt, not volume and screen brightness indicator. I know there's a small software on Windows called keybard jedi, which isn't very usable.

Comment: (As far as I know, in stock OS X, this is only visible when enabling Sticky Keys in Universal Access, or when showing the Keyboard Viewer. Hence, I changed the title.)