# is there an onscreen keyboard with key highlight?

Tags: on-screen-keyboard

In order to improve my typing skills, I am looking for an application providing an onscreen keyboard, whose keys would be highlighted when typed, allowing me to check my typing and memorize the keyboard layout without having to take my eyes off the screen.

Do you know if such an application exists ? (And if there is, is it cross-platform, open-sourced ?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it wasnt cross platform What OS is it that you would most want it to be for?  Does the keyboard display "intercept" or additionally show input while your typing into another program?

Comment: @Psycogeek If not cross platform the OS I would want it for is Windows. I'm not sure if I understand your other question, but I think the answer would be "additionnaly" : the keyboard should just show which key I typed while using my other programs.

Comment: would displaying just what the current key pressed do?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Do you mean just displaying the caption on the key currently pressed ? That would be a start.. that's a good idea actually. In fact I am mainly struggling with the modifier keys because you don't have a direct feedback on screen when using them. For example I sometimes end up typing ALT+Z instead of a CTRL+Z.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/104421/windows-utility-to-render-which-key-i-am-pressing-on-screen this question has a few options. I do think this is VERY similar, but not quite the same as that

Comment: keypose is quite good, however it is not configurable so I prefer osdHotkey. +1 for your comment however !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This OSK claims to:

> When you press keys on the real keyboard, your keystrokes are shown on
>   the virtual keyboard, which allows you to control the process of
>   typing without having to move your eyes from the keyboard to the
>   monitor and back.

http://hot-virtual-keyboard.com/help-online/

it is not free, but has some trial capabilty.

This just displays keypresses,  [romeosa.com/osdHotkey/help.html](http://romeosa.com/osdHotkey/help.html)  I did not find the free OSK thing that is just for testing keyboards/keymaps.

Comment: osdHotkey is the closest to what I was looking for. There are some problems like the "Fn", "right click", "japanese character conversion" keys not detected, but I will do with it for now. Thank you !

Comment: Hot Virtual Keyboard is fantastic, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 4):

There's an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script available that draws an [on-screen keyboard with key highlight](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/KeyboardOnScreen.htm).

[image]

The keyboard is drawn at the center bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To improve your typing skills, use this **[Typing Test](http://www.typingtest.com)** for better practice.

**[Typing Master](http://www.rapidtyping.com/best-typing-tutors/typingmaster.html)** is one more application which you can buy.

Comment: Thank you, I also know TypingClub which can be integrated in Chrome. However, I am not looking for a tutorial but for a tool that I can use while doing my work at the same time.

Comment: In this case, my best suggestion is to get finger tip pratice through one of these applications and you can start with better speed at your work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the best suitable for my own needs. 
With this utility I can show Keyboard and Mouse Keystrokes in correct order exactly.Im using in my classroom and for building my video tutorials for my students is: 
[Mouse and Keyboard On Screen Display for Video Tutors - Moukey](https://gumroad.com/l/rbLuu)
I lost enough time and I dont wanna lose you too. searching for better choice for nothing.
https://gumroad.com/l/rbLuu

Answer (score 0):

(Feedback)

Not exactly an answer to my initial question, but in the end what helped me most in improving my typing skills (which was the underlying problem I wanted to solve), has been playing the Sega game [The Typing of the Dead: Overkill](http://store.steampowered.com/app/246580/).
Awesome game!