# Is it possible to show key presses and mouse input visually?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

Is there a way to visually show if keypresses and programmed mouse-buttons are properly sending their input?

Obviously, my keyboard is registering letter keys. But I can't tell whether my programmed mouse-buttons are properly sending their input, or if the problem is further down the chain with Windows' properly acting on the input. Likewise, sometimes my windows-key goes "out", but I'm not sure where in the chain of events it's failing.

Comment: I would also recommend checking out the following SU page:
http://superuser.com/questions/104421/windows-utility-to-render-which-key-i-am-pressing-on-screen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this [blog post](http://dan.hersam.com/2009/05/01/how-to-display-keystrokes-for-screencasts-on-windows/) seems there are a number of scripts for [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

> [On Screen Keyboard](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/KeyboardOnScreen.ahk) displays a virtual keyboard and shows each
> keystroke as you type it. The button press visual is subtle, but it’s
> my favorite of the three.

[image]

and

> [ShowOff](https://www.dcmembers.com/skrommel/download/showoff/) puts a plain white box in the corner of your screen and
> displays every keystroke and mouse click. You can change what keys to
> show, the font, colors and position as well as drag the window around.

[image: showoff]

and

> [osdHotkey](http://www.romeosa.com/osdHotkey/help.html) is similar to ShowOff, displaying a window with colors that can be customized.

[image]

Comment: I believe the built in on screen keyboard in Windows also shows the keys you press on the physical keyboard, though it doesn't show mouse clicks.

Comment: dead link, can you update?

Answer (score 4):

[QiPress](http://aalapshah.in/qipress) is a Windows plug-n-play utility I have written, with a variety of controls on what and how to display key presses on the screen.

Comment: dead link,  still active?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for Moukey.
I can show Keyboard and Mouse Keystrokes in correct order .
Im using in my classroom and for building my video tutorials for my students is:
[Mouse and Keyboard On Screen Display for Video Tutors - Moukey](https://gumroad.com/l/rbLuu)
I lost enough time and I dont wanna lose anyone too. searching for better one for nothing.
https://gumroad.com/l/rbLuu