When I press 'w' on my keyboard in firefox, it switches to my first tab. How do I stop this?
Recently, I've found that if I press the 'w' key in Firefox, without any modifiers such as shift or ctrl, and I'm not entering text in a box or similar field, it switches tabs to the first one in the window. Then, if I press it again, it goes back to the tab I was just on. This is very annoying, and I want to stop it. How can I do that? I can't find any information on how the w-key interacts with tabs except ctrl-w closing them, which I already know about and is obvioiusly not applicable here.

No repro on Firefox 115.15 esr

What version of firefox and which operating system show the problem? Can the problem be repeated on more than one system?

Have you tried another keyboard? It could be a bad keyboard sending Ctrl+Tab.

Knowing what key commands cause switching to the first tab will probably help point you in the right direction, and using a tool for displaying key presses will probably confirm things, but in general, if you're getting a behavior like this, the first thing to do is what DrMoishe Pippik suggested: try a different keyboard. Also, knowing the OS and software versions you are running is rather important to our understanding the problem. Please EDIT your post to add the requested information, and try what we've suggested and report on the outcome as well. https://superuser.com/a/594153
